# How to Deselect same checkbox again?

Tags: react-native

When i select a checkbox, i am not able to de-select same checkbox again.
I want to de-select same checkbox again when I firstly checked. Here below is the sample of code on which i am working.

```
checkBoxChanged = (AttibuteCollectionId) => {
        var value = AttibuteCollectionId
        console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^", value)
        this.setState({ checkedCheckBox: !this.state.checkedCheckBox })
        alert(this.state.checkedCheckBox)
    }

{this.state.checkboxAttCollection.map((item, i) => {
                                        return (<View key={item.AttibuteCollectionId} style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                            
                                            <CheckBox
                                                center
                                                title="yes"
                                                checked={this.state.checkedCheckBox}
                                                //     value={this.state.checked}
                                                onValueChange={() => this.checkBoxChanged(item.AttibuteCollectionId)}
                                            />
                                            <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                                                <Text>{item.AttibuteCollectionName}</Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </View>)
                                    })}
```

**Please provide me solution for this in order to get desired output.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
checkBoxChanged = (index) => {
       const newData = [...this.state.checkboxAttCollection];
       const newData[index].checked = !newData[index].checked;
       this.setState({checkboxAttCollection: newData});       
}

{this.state.checkboxAttCollection.map((item, i) => {
       return (
                                            
          <CheckBox
            ......
            checked={item.checked || false}
             onValueChange={() => this.checkBoxChanged(i)}
          />
})}
```